# Minus Query for Numerical column with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have two tables with Identical column structure.

```
Table A

Key Value
a 123.452
b 127.851
c 128.478

Table B
Key Value
a   124.46
b   127.578
d   576
```

Now I want to show all rows in Table A which are not present in table B. But there is also a condition to neglect a difference of +/- 0.01 in value column and consider them as equal.

So the result should be like

```
Key Value
b 127.851
c 128.478
```

I know the minus query can be used but it would not take into consideration the additional condition.

Comment: I don't think your sample data matches your condition.  All three rows match your condition.

Comment: Let me update this

Answer (score 1):

One method is not exists:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where abs(b.value - a.value) <= 0.01
                 );
```

Comment: What does select 1 specify ?

Comment: Actuall both the data are fetch from same table. I have a date column which will give different set of rows.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh . . . The "1" is arbitrary.  `not exists` is based on whether any *rows* are returned, not the values in the rows.

Answer (score 1):

> Actuall both the data are fetch from same table. I have a date column which will give different set of rows.

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and compare the values using `BETWEEN`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd00c/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( date_column, key, value ) AS
SELECT DATE '2017-01-01', 'a', 123.452 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-01-01', 'b', 127.851 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-01-01', 'c', 128.478 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-01-02', 'a', 123.46 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-01-02', 'b', 127.841 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-01-02', 'd', 576 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT key, value
FROM   table_name a
WHERE  date_column = DATE '2017-01-01'
AND    NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table_name b
  WHERE  date_column = DATE '2017-01-02'
  AND    a.key = b.key
  AND    a.value BETWEEN b.value - 0.01 AND b.value + 0.01
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd00c/1/0)**:

```
| KEY |   VALUE |
|-----|---------|
|   c | 128.478 |
```

Comment: However It is not showing the additonal rows. Say c 128.478 in this case.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Added some sample data and output - can you give an example of where it is not working as my example shows the additional rows.

Comment: I have not added key in the translated SQL since there are around 12 columns which will serve as key. I will add them and see

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.key = b.key
 WHERE (b.key IS NULL OR ABS (a.VALUE - b.VALUE) < 0.01);
```

For your data `b` wont be fetched as the `difference` is `more` than `0.01`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` on self.

```
SELECT a.key,a.value FROM 
TableA a LEFT JOIN TableA b
ON a.key = b.key 
AND ABS(a.value - b.value ) <= 0.01
WHERE TRUNC(a.dt) = :date1
AND TRUNC(b.dt) = :date2
AND b.value IS NULL;
```